# synology docker rocket chat setup

Tags: docker, synology

I have a question reg. running RocketChat from a Synology NAS DS415+

The Docker is a GUI version installed from Package Center.

You download the image and launch a container - then run through a UI setup of that container.

I launched a mongo:latest and a rocket.chat:latest container with default settings.
The mongo starts and runs - but the rocket.chat container starts - runs a few seconds and then shuts down.

What to do?

Here is a log output from a rocket.chat start attempt, with mongo running:

`/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
stdout
09:43:29
                        throw(ex);
stdout
09:43:29
                        ^
stdout
09:43:30
MongoError: failed to connect to server [db:27017] on first connect
stdout
09:43:30
    at Object.Future.wait (/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
stdout
09:43:30
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:211:27)
stdout
09:43:30
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
stdout
09:43:30
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
stdout
09:43:30
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore.js:784:19)
stdout
09:43:30
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:99:40)
stdout
09:43:30
    at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
stdout
09:43:30
    at new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
stdout
09:43:30
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
stdout
09:43:30
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
stdout
09:43:30
    - - - - -
stdout
09:43:30
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:326:35)
stdout
09:43:30
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
stdout
09:43:30
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:169:7)
stdout
09:43:30
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
stdout
09:43:30
    at [object Object].g (events.js:260:16)
stdout
09:43:30
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
stdout
09:43:30
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:172:7)
stdout
09:43:30
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:175:49)
stdout
09:43:30
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
stdout
09:43:30
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run Rocket.chat on a DS716+II running DSM 6.1.6, thanks to a discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/synology/comments/4p284n/anyone_have_any_experience_getting_lets_chat_or/).

First, launch your mongo:latest container with default settings.
Now before launching the rocket.chat:latest container, add these settings (right click on the container > modify):

- In the Links tab, click the '+' icon and select your mongo container. In the Alias field, enter 'db' as value (without ' ')
- In the Environment tab, add a new value, enter '-d' as variable and 'rocket.chat' as value.

Now you should be able to start the container and access it through http://your_local_ip:3000 (or whatever port you choose for your rocket.chat container).